# Magento 2 Order creates Shipment twice that causes an error

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, shipment, magento2.2.8

If I click the ship button in the order, sometimes I got 404 Error. I only encountered this error if I use Microsoft Edge. 
In my Network Monitor, the POST request sometimes sending twice.

[image]

[image]

Is there anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: I've added this code "this.onclick=null;" in vendor/magento/module-shipping/Block/Adminhtml/Create/Items.php at line 94 to prevent submitting the button twice and it is now fixed for the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help to fix this issue.

https://github.com/abad93/SubmitShipment

Comment: Thank you @Francis ,

Were you able to track down to the root of the bug?